# Logical clean up

Tags: php

I am currently having logical structure errors and I can't seem to think of a proper way of writing it out so it looks clean. Currently, I have a table in my database named `USER`. User has 6 fields out of the many, named: `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`, `fifth`, `sixth`.
What my code does is switch the data with two of the fields. So for example: the data in `first` is changed with the data in `sixth`.

**Before**: First - 1, Sixth - 6 
**After**: First - 6, Sixth - 1

Currently, what I have is something that looks very messy, and I'm not sure how I can clean it up.

```
if($switch == true){ /* $switch just indicates if the numbers being switched is one of the fields i.e. first, second, etc.. */
                if($slot == 1){ // The number is being switched into the first slot
                    if($first == $number){
                        return 1; // error, can't switch with itself
                    } else if ($second == $number){
                        $temp = $first;
                        // 1st QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN FIRST, WITH THE DATA IN THE SECOND
                        // 2nd QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN SECOND, WITH THE INFO STORED IN VARIABLE $temp
                    } else if ($third == $number){
                        $temp = $first;
                        // 1st QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN FIRST, WITH THE DATA IN THE THIRD
                        // 2nd QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN THIRD, WITH THE INFO STORED IN VARIABLE $temp 
                    } // ... continues to check for 4, 5, 6...
                } else if($slot == 2){ /* Then checks to see if it was slot 2, i.e. Second */
                    // ....
                } else if($slot == 3){ /* Then checks to see if it was slot 3, i.e. Third */
                    // ....
                } else if($slot == 4){ /* Then checks to see if it was slot 4, i.e. Fourth */
                    // ....
                } else if($slot == 5){ /* Then checks to see if it was slot 5, i.e. Fifth */
                    // ....
                } else if($slot == 6){ /* Then checks to see if it was slot 6, i.e. Sixth */
                    // ....
                }
```

}

It continues for each slot, , 6 times each... I know it's bad programming but I have just started learning PHP (it's my first language, so bear with me). Any suggestions on what I can do to make this cleaner? Or even a better way of writing it? If anyone cares to explain to me over Skype or anything, I would be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// This function returns the column name for the specified slot
function getSlotColumn($slotNum)
{
    switch($slotNum)
    {
        case 1:
            retrun "first";

        case 2:
            return "second";

        ......
    }
}
```

then in the switching function

```
// This function swaps the values of the two specified slots
function swapValues($slot1Num, $slot2Num)
{
    if($slot1Num == $slot2Num) return;
    if($slot1Num < 1 || $slot1Num > 6) return;
    if($slot2Num < 1 || $slot2Num > 6) return;

    $slot1Col = getSlotColumn($slot1Num);
    $slot2Col = getSlotColumn($slot2Num);

            //get value of the first slot
    $slot1Val = //SELECT $slot1Col FROM ... WHERE ... slot

    // Now since we have the value of the first slot, we can update it from the second slot with this pseudo query
    //UPDATE ... SET $slot1Col = $slot2Col WHERE ...

    // Then update second slot from the value in $slot1Val
    //UPDATE ... SET $slot2Col = $slot1Val WHERE ...
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if(switch == true)
{
    swapValues(1, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`switch` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
if($switch == true){ 
    switch($slot) {
        case 1 :
            if($first == $number){
                return 1; // error, can't switch with itself
            } else if ($second == $number){
                $temp = $first;
                // 1st QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN FIRST, WITH THE DATA IN THE SECOND
                // 2nd QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN SECOND, WITH THE INFO STORED IN VARIABLE $temp
            } else if ($third == $number){
                $temp = $first;
                // 1st QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN FIRST, WITH THE DATA IN THE THIRD
                // 2nd QUERY TO UPDATE THE DATA IN THIRD, WITH THE INFO STORED IN VARIABLE $temp 
            } 
            break;
        case 2 :
            // ....
            break;
        case 3 :
            // ....
            break;
        case 4 :
            // ....
            break;
        case 5 :
            // ....
            break;
        case 6 :
            // ....
            break;
        default:
            // ...
    }    
}
```

You will notice a `default` at the bottom. It's always good to have one in place in case none of your conditions match.

Also notice the `break` keyword. Without it the code block does not stop at the end and will "fall through" to the next block. This can be handy sometimes but not in your case.

Comment: Doesn't make a real clean up though. The OP would still have 36 conditions to check

Comment: is there any way to reduce the number of conditions? @zerkms